# Core Data adding entities at runtime

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am rewriting the question to help clarify and get rid of a lot of code I wrote that really doesn't help.

I am using a .xcdatamodel for my initial schema, but I need to add entities to my schema at runtime and therefore I need to add a new NSManagedObjectModel and copy over the existing entities and then add the new entities.

If I create a new NSPersistantStore first and then ask my NSMigrationManager to migrate, I get an error about how it can't move the source model to destination path because file already exists.

If I simply ask my NSMigrationManager to migrate, then it just crashes without any error codes or anything in the debugger.

```
NSMappingModel *mappingModel = [NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:originalModel destinationModel:newModel error:&error];
NSMigrationManager *manager = [[NSMigrationManager alloc] initWithSourceModel:originalModel destinationModel:newModel];

if (![manager migrateStoreFromURL:[originalStore URL]
                             type:NSSQLiteStoreType
                          options:[self autoMigrationOptions]
                 withMappingModel:mappingModel
                 toDestinationURL:[NSPersistentStore MR_urlForStoreName:[self nextStoreName]]
                  destinationType:NSSQLiteStoreType
               destinationOptions:[self autoMigrationOptions]
                            error:&error])
{
    return NO;
}
```

The URL's are all good, the mapping model looks good when I log it to the console, the manager exists, etc. In this case I did not create the NSPersistantStore yet, but according to the NSMigrationManager class reference if a store does not exist at the destination URL then one is automatically created.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the locations where you save the CoreData stores, if you try to save outside the sandbox it fails. Log the sourceStoreURL and destinationStoreURL variables just before the migrateStoreFromURL call.

Comment: @MichelePercich you were right, my paths were all messed up. Now I have a new error: reason=Can't copy source store to destination store path. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of destination path?

Comment: destinationURL=file://localhost/Users/thawe/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/6200B429-F483-4CD8-B3D7-D38F223B53F9/Library/Application%20Support/DynamicTest/NewStore.sqlite   sourceURL=file://localhost/Users/thawe/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/6200B429-F483-4CD8-B3D7-D38F223B53F9/Library/Application%20Support/DynamicTest/DynamicTest.sqlite

Comment: Check if this file already exist: file://localhost/Users/thawe/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone‌​%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/6200B429-F483-4CD8-B3D7-D38F223B53F9/Library/Applic‌​ation%20Support/DynamicTest/NewStore.sqlite. Also, does the error has an error code? It should have.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)" UserInfo=0x8172b70 {NSUnderlyingError=0x81f32c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.) File does not exist at path.

Comment: The Cocoa error 516 means file already exists:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html. But maybe it is generated by the fileManager methods at the end, have you checked which line does produce the error?